# how to add bootstrap or materialize-css to angular?

Tags: angular

I have imported materialize-css into my app. Then I have run angular `cli` and `ng` serve. but angular `cli` gives me the following error :

```
Invalid JSON character: "" at 0:0.
Error: Invalid JSON character: "" at 0:0.
```

Comment: check angular cli and seach for typo or provide more detail about your problem how did you install materialize css?

Comment: edited question to remove angular 5 or 6.   Its confusing what version you are using!